# Shared data between certain views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to share data on all my frontend views but not on the backend or dashboard pages.

```
  view()->composer('*', function ($view)
  {
      // Some eloquent queries to return data that would only be used on frontend pages/views
    view()->share('data', $data);
  }
```

The problem with this approach is that it runs on every view render, is there a way i can limit it to only frontend views?

As an alternative i am thinking to create separate routes group and with some middleware to share the data between route group something like below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['frontend']], function () { //Frontend Routes });

// frontend Middleware

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        View::share(
            'data',  'data'
        );

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Can someone please guide me what is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: I would go with your idea with route groups